# If I use CWAC-Presentation, can I access phone`s screen?

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I finding phone`s screen mirroring API.

I wrote at goolgle Developer, I got reply about Presentation API.

but, I still don`t know how can I access phone's screen.

If I use CWAC_Presentation API, can I make mirroring application?
(exactly like chromecast's mirroring function..)

At https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation provide "Mirroring Presentation Classes",
It`s simple and great API. But I can't understand it.

so.. My question is..

1. Can "Presentation API" access the phone's screen without root?

   -> How it works? Is it provide "display capture"? or just "display location"?
2. Can I make mirroring application like chromecast's mirroring function?
3. Should I choose "Display manager" or "MediaRouter" ?
4. Is any sample or app about "Mirroring?"(not miracast, it`s phone to pc(tv))
5. **Finally, I want buffers of the phone screen. Can I?**

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can "Presentation API" access the phone's screen without root?

No.

> Can I make mirroring application like chromecast's mirroring function?

No.

> Should I choose "Display manager" or "MediaRouter" ?

Neither will help you.

> Is any sample or app about "Mirroring?"(not miracast, it`s phone to pc(tv))

Chromecast's mirroring *is* Miracast.

> Finally, I want buffers of the phone screen. Can I?

Only with root. This has nothing whatsoever to do with the `Presentation` API.